# replace trademark symbol (™) with html code in php

Tags: php, string, magento

I have following string:

`$str='Enzyme™ is a trademark';`

Now I want to put this string in a CSV file like: `'Enzyme&trade; is a trademark'`,  `because if "™" placed like as it is in CSV file, Magento import product setup simply escapes it.
Can anyone please help me on this issue as I googled a lot but not found a correct suggestion. Sorry 4 my bad english.

I tried following code:

```
htmlentities($db->col['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");//but it simply removes '™'<br> 
htmlentities($db->col['title'], ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8"); //removes whole string <br>
```

Comment: htmlentities: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: @Jite I have tried it but no result

Comment: Show what you tried (edit question and add some code).

Comment: `php> echo htmlentities ('™') //⇒ &trade;` This is what I tried and it perfectly works.

Comment: @mudasobwa  it works well in php file but while putting it into CSV cell, it appears again like '™'

Answer (score 0):

Using the global function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in php, you can convert a string with 'special characters' to one using html entities.

```
$variable = "Enzyme™ is a trademark";
$convertedVariable = htmlentities($variable);
echo $convertedVariable; // echos: Enzyme&trade; is a trademark
```

Comment: Yes but while putting it in CSV file, it appears again like " Enzyme™ "

Comment: Are you inserting the converted string or the original string into the CSV file? The `htmlentities` function do not change the original value (its not passed by reference) but returns a new value (the 'fixed' string).

Comment: @AJ.. Then you probably have [encoding problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: I want to put the same string in CSV so that it could be reflected well on html page after importing is done. but my issue is, when it appears in CSV with it's original value, Magento simply escapes this row :(